# After trying to resign three times in the past year, my company is trying to hold me

Tags: resignation

I am a software developer in a product development company. Currently leading a team.

After putting paper three times in last one year, my company is trying to hold me still. They are saying that I am very important to the company. And now the third time, they are ready to give shares also for some good amount.

But my Director(to whom I am reporting), who always works on employees psychology, I am afraid of him. What he will do in future to me. He never show any proper respect to his employees.

I have 8 years of experience in this company.

If I stay in this company, in two years, I will surely become a manager.
But the problem is that work will never be so organized. No planning. Mostly, hard work gets wasted. Just because of one great person, company is running with a steady growth.

But I want to work in a company, where a work comes to software developer is well organized. My hard work will be appreciated.

Which one will be good. Whether to go out or stay.

Comment: When you say you resigned three times, do you mean that you _tried_ to resign, but they pulled you back in with great offers? Normally a resignation is the end, not something you can do multiple times...

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to resign.

Comment: Which country is this in? What keeps you from simply walking out the door?

Comment: work will never be so organized. No planning. Mostly, hard work gets wasted. Just because of one great person, company is running with a steady growth. And its in India.

Comment: You want a Yacht, a really big one!

Comment: How exactly does one "try" (and fail) to resign?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't tell you what is best for you, but I will say this, the fact that you have tried to resign three times in a year tells me that you really don't want to be there.  If you are looking for satisfaction and some level of happiness in your job, it seems like you've already decided that your current employer can't provide that.

In fairness to them, you need to make a final decision and follow through on it.  Every time you try to resign and then decide to stay, you are making it unclear as to your intentions and that may lead to the way you are being treated now.

Comment: Agreed, typically once you've hit the point of persuing resignation if you're retained it's because the counter (typically financial gain) is tempting enough to sway you. Generally though that's only a good idea to accept if the reason for considering resignation is not feeling you're properly paid for services rendered. (If your mad about poor planning, more money won't make things better long term)